# Python: making a project

Tags: python

hello i am new in python and i started learning from a book called "automate the boring stuff" and there was a project in it called Character Picture Grid and i did it but i think my code is little bit stupid and anyone tell me the right way to do this project ? :D thank you ^^

code:

```
grid = [['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
    ['.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.', '.'],
    ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', '.'],
    ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.'],
    ['.', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'],
    ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.'],
    ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', '.'],
    ['.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.', '.'],
    ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']]

def x_y_1(grid):
for y in range(9):
    for x in [0]:
        print(grid[y][x],end='')
print(end='\n')
def x_y_2(grid):
for y in range(9):
    for x in [1]:
        print(grid[y][x],end='')
print(end='\n')
def x_y_3(grid):
for y in range(9):
    for x in [2]:
        print(grid[y][x],end='')
print(end='\n')
def x_y_4(grid):
for y in range(9):
    for x in [3]:
        print(grid[y][x],end='')
print(end='\n')
def x_y_5(grid):
for y in range(9):
    for x in [4]:
        print(grid[y][x],end='')
print(end='\n')
def x_y_6(grid):
for y in range(9):
    for x in [5]:
        print(grid[y][x],end='')
print(end='\n')
x_y_1(grid)
x_y_2(grid)
x_y_3(grid)
x_y_4(grid)
x_y_5(grid)
x_y_6(grid)
```

Comment: What is your task?

Comment: Could you please tell us what you want to do ?

Comment: If it's working, consider asking on https://codereview.stackexchange.com. Otherwise, question seeking for debugging help must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.

Comment: Also have you read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)? Definitely not, because you don't have the Informed badge. "It's not a discussion forum. There's no chit-chat.".

Comment: Please 1/ fix your code indentation 2/ clearly explain what your problem is (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: aha ok i am new here so sorry if i made u guys mad :/ anyway thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's all about the loops. This way you don't have to duplicate the step over and over. The for loop does that for you.

```
grid = [['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
        ['.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.', '.'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', '.'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.'],
        ['.', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', '.'],
        ['.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.', '.'],
        ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']]

for y in range(len(grid[0])):
 for x in range(len(grid)):
     print(grid[x][y], end='') 
 print()
```

Answer (score 1):

I am thinking you are looking to print the array element by element.

```
grid = [['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'], 
        ['.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.', '.'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', '.'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.'],
        ['.', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', '.'],
        ['.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.', '.'],
        ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']]

# You can create one generic function instead
def x_y(grid, index):
    for y in range(6):      
        print(grid[index][y],end='')
    print(end='\n')

for index_ in range(len(grid)):
    x_y(grid, index_)
```

Answer (score 1):

I am also just reading this book, and i think the answer your want should be like below.

```
def x_y(grid, index):
    for y in range(9):      
        print(grid[y][index],end='')
    print(end='\n')

for index_ in range(6):
    x_y(grid, index_)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
def rev():
x = 0
y = 0
while y < 6:
    print(grid[x][y], end = '')
    x += 1
    if x == 8:
        print(grid[x][y])
        x = 0
        y += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

My function starts with a for loop for the y variable, then continues to the x- for loop that prints them using the "end=''" argument to connect the x coordinates for the grid together. Outside of the x-for loop, I used print('') to get a new line.  the y-for loop iterates down a total of 6 times to complete the picture.

---

```
grid = [['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
        ['.', '0', '0', '.', '.', '.'],
        ['0', '0', '0', '0', '.', '.'],
        ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '.'],
        ['.', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'],
        ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '.'],
        ['0', '0', '0', '0', '.', '.'],
        ['.', '0', '0', '.', '.', '.'],
        ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']]

def characterPictureGrid(grid):
    
    for y in range(6):  #also could have used range(len(grid[0]))

        for x in range(len(grid)):
            print(grid[x][y], end='')   #prints the x coordinates together
        print('')                       #automatically starts new line
     
characterPictureGrid(grid)
```